# Can i use interfaces in code of WPF usercontrols?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Some years ago we made WinForm controls which implemented interfaces with all common properties and methods for our usercontrols.
Can i do the same in WPF usercontrols (not customcontrols!)?
As i do it i have the Problem, that some of the Interface defined properties which have the same names as properties inherited by the class UserControl are not implemented.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a comment to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36893414/1136211) you were asked "What purpose does the interface serve?". It doesn't seem to make any sense. The "common properties" of UI controls are declared by their base classes, i.e. all controls derived from class `Control` inherit their `Background` property from that class.

Comment: It's because i'm used to define common properties for multiple classes - or in that case usercontrols - in interfaces. But in WPF UserControls this seems to be out of time.

Comment: Could you please let me know which interface in particular?? 
But it should be actually possible to implement interfaces. But if there is some conflict like this, you might need to implement those properties.